# Why are some messages browser alerts and others are custom?

Tags: discussion, user-interface

Popup messages on Stack Overflow are displayed in inconsistent styles. Some of them are standard browser/system alerts, while others are styled to match the theme of Stack Overflow.

---

[Link to screen recording of 2 inconsistently-styled popup messages being displayed back-to-back](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxRMbmixnUEoVmwybW9VU0llQ2M)

---

> [image]
>
> **A browser/system alert**

---

> [image]
>
> **A Stack-Exchange-style red popup message**

The first message in the screen recording was a browser/system alert, but the second one was a Stack-Exchange-style red popup message.

Why is there an inconsistency in the way popup messages are displayed?

Comment: You might have been (unintentionally double) clicking too fast?

Comment: Just linking to the video isn't really good. Please try to explain what exactly happens in prose [at your question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/327754/edit).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I added extra detail and images to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browser alerts require immediate attention of the user, therefore they are more suitable for irreversible actions (such as unupvoting a comment) than SE popups which automatically disappear after a short time.

Comment: Not all popups automatically disappear.